# How is it possible to use react-hook-form with react-datepicker select range?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, react-datepicker

I want to select a time range with **react-datepicker**,
and also use **react-hook-form** to validate when `onBlur` without `input`,
here is my code:

```
<Controller
    control={control}
    name='time'
    rules={{ required: true }}
    render={({
        field: { value, onChange, onBlur }
    }) => (
        <Datepicker
            dateFormat='yyyy/MM/dd h:mm aa'
            onChange={onChange}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            selected={value}
            showTimeSelect
        />
    )}
/>
```

I can choose one date and time in one picker and do validation right now,
it works, but if I want to choose two date and time in one picker, what should I do?
How do I make **react-hook-form** identify the start or end time in picker?
is it possible?

Comment: i just posted the answer here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/72585781/19320134

Answer (score 2):

I've got the exact same issue last week, here is the solution...

You just need to pass (**at least**) the value to the "**Controller function**", you achieve that using only the field object.

In any case, When the **DatePicker component** is used for a date range, it will require a two-position vector data type, where the start and end dates are stored as a string. But if you try to manipulate and control this component via the **onChange function** that comes from the reack-hook-form it's gonna screw up the entire thing, because is made  for a one-to-one data flux. Then the processes are done separately but the vector is still sent to the controller. Here is the code!

```
              const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState([null, null]);
              const [startDate, endDate] = dateRange;
              <Controller
                //is a prop that we get back from the useForm Hook and pass into the input.
                control={control}
                //is how React Hook Form tracks the value of an input internally.
                name={name}
                //render is the most important prop; we pass a render function here.
                render={({
                  //The function has three keys: field , fieldState, and formState.
                  field, // The field object exports two things (among others): value and onChange
                }) => (
                  <>
                    <DatePicker
                      selectsRange={true}
                      startDate={startDate}
                      endDate={endDate}
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        setDateRange(e);
                        field.onChange(e);
                      }}
                      isClearable={true}
                      className="form-control"
                    />
                  </>
                )}
                rules={{
                  required: `The  ${label} field is required`,
                }}
              />
```